# Test para Widget en flutter que contiene una función aparte la cual retorna un widget

Tags: funciones, flutter, dart, test, widget

espero que se encuentren bien, tengo el siguiente tengo un problema, tengo un widget qué necesita ser validado con pruebas unitarias, sin embargo no puedo abarcar todo el rango de coverage, porque tengo una función que retorna un widget pero esta depende de una función para ser mostrad.

```
class SettingsPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(dashboardController);

    return GenericPageBuilderWidget(
      title: "Configuración",
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: context.height(.025)),
            ConfigCardWidget(
                title: 'Seguridad',
                subtitle: 'Agrega protección extra a tu cuenta MO\$',
                path: icons.seguridad,
                onTap: () => context.push(Routes.secureOption)),
            SizedBox(height: context.height(.025)),
            ConfigCardWidget(
                title: 'Transacciones',
                subtitle: 'Protege tu cuenta de toda amenaza externa',
                path: icons.transferir,
                iconSize: context.width(.08),
                onTap: () => context.push(Routes.transactionsConfig)),
            SizedBox(height: context.height(.05)),
            if (state.acountList.isNotEmpty) ...products(context, ref),
            const FooterInfoWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  products(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(dashboardController);
    List<Widget> list = [
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: TitleTextWidget(content: 'Tus productos', color: colors.titles, size: 18),
      ),
    ];
    for (ProductsAccountsListModel data in state.acountList) {
      list.addAll([
        SizedBox(height: context.height(.01)),
        ConfigCardWidget(
            title: (data.getTitle ??  "").capitalize(),
            subtitle: data.account ?? "",
            path: _getIcon(data.productType ?? ""),
            color: Color(int.parse(data.getColor??"0")),
            iconSize: context.width(.1),
            enableTrailing: true,
            text: "Activa",
            onTap: () => ExpCampaignModal(context: context).show()),
      ]);
    }
    return list;
  }

  _getIcon(String value) {
    final icon = {
      "0003": icons.cuentaAhorro,
      "0004": icons.cuentaDigital,
      "0008": icons.cuentaDigital,
    };
    return icon[value];
  }
}
```

Este sería la pagina a validar.

y este es mi test

```
void main() {
  getInjection(sl);

  group("SettingsPage", () {
    late AuthUseCase authUseCase;
    late CreditMessageUseCase messageUseCase;
    late ProductsAccountsUseCase productAccountUseCase;
    late VerificationThirdFacetecUseCase thirdFacetecUseCase;
    late SavingsAccountUseCase savingsAccountUseCase;
    late ListUseCase listUseCase;
    late ListMosUseCase listMosUseCase;
    late CreditHomeUseCase useCaseIp;
    late UsersLastConnectionsUseCase lastConnectionsUseCase;
    late SharedPreferenceUseCase sharedPreferenceUseCase;

    late DashboardController dashboardController;
    final mockContext = MockBuildContext();
    setUp(() {
      authUseCase = mock.MockAuthUseCaseHome();
      messageUseCase = MockCreditMessageUseCase();
      productAccountUseCase = MockProductsAccountsUseCase();
      thirdFacetecUseCase = MockVerificationThirdFacetecUseCase();
      savingsAccountUseCase = MockSavingsAccountUseCase();
      listUseCase = MockListUseCase();
      listMosUseCase = MockListMosUseCase();
      useCaseIp = MockCreditHomeUseCase();
      lastConnectionsUseCase = MockUsersLastConnectionsUseCase();
      sharedPreferenceUseCase = MockUseSharedPreferenceUseCase();
      dashboardController = DashboardController(
          authUseCase,
          messageUseCase,
          productAccountUseCase,
          thirdFacetecUseCase,
          savingsAccountUseCase,
          listUseCase,
          listMosUseCase,
          useCaseIp,
          lastConnectionsUseCase,
          sharedPreferenceUseCase);
    });

      ProductsAccountsListModel acountList = ProductsAccountsListModel(
          account: 'Test',
          productType: 'Test',
          productDescription: 'Test',
          balance: 'Test',
          dateInitial: 'Test',
        );
    final container = ProviderContainer();

    tearDown(() {
      container.dispose();
    });

    testWidgets('SettingsPage options', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      dashboardController.state = DashboardState(acountList: [
        acountList,
      ]);
      final dashboardControllerProvider = Provider<DashboardController>((ref) {
        return dashboardController;
      });
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: ProviderScope(overrides: [
            dashboardControllerProvider.overrideWithValue(dashboardController),
          ], child: const SettingsPage()),
        ),
      );

      /// act

      /// assert
      expect(find.byType(SettingsPage), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('Configuración'), findsOneWidget);
      expect(dashboardController.state.acountList, equals([acountList]));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      if (dashboardController.state.acountList.isNotEmpty) {
        expect(find.text('Tus productos'), findsOneWidget);
        expect(find.byType(ConfigCardWidget), findsWidgets);
        expect(find.text('Activa'), findsOneWidget);
        expect(find.text('Test'), findsOneWidget);

      }
    });
  });
}
```

como puedo primero hacer que funciones porque esta parte no la encuentra en el test

```
if (dashboardController.state.acountList.isNotEmpty) {
        expect(find.text('Tus productos'), findsOneWidget);
        expect(find.byType(ConfigCardWidget), findsWidgets);
        expect(find.text('Activa'), findsOneWidget);
        expect(find.text('Test'), findsOneWidget);

      }
```

y segundo que pueda validar que product se mostro correctamente? Les agradezco su ayuda y gracias!